# PrimeFaces Drag & Drop not working if other portlets contain <form> tags

Tags: jsf, primefaces, liferay-6.2

If I have a Liferay page which includes a Liferay Web Content Display with a `form` tag and then a PrimeFaces portlet with `p:droppable` and `p:draggable`, the Drag & Drop functionality does not work.

My XHTML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<f:view xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <h:head />
    <h:body>

        <h:form id="carForm">
            <p:fieldset id="availableCarsField" legend="AvailableCars">
                <p:dataGrid id="availableCars" var="car" value="#{dndCarsView.cars}" columns="3">
                    <p:panel id="pnl" header="#{car.id}" style="text-align:center">
                        <h:panelGrid columns="1" style="width:100%">
                            <h:outputText value="#{car.id}" />
                        </h:panelGrid>
                    </p:panel>

                    <p:draggable for="pnl" revert="true" handle=".ui-panel-titlebar" stack=".ui-panel" />
                </p:dataGrid>
            </p:fieldset>

            <p:fieldset id="selectedCars" legend="Selected Cars" style="margin-top:20px">
                <p:outputPanel id="dropArea">
                    <h:outputText value="!!!Drop here!!!" rendered="#{empty dndCarsView.droppedCars}" style="font-size:24px;" />
                    <p:dataTable id="selectedCarsTable" var="car" value="#{dndCarsView.droppedCars}"
                                 rendered="#{not empty dndCarsView.droppedCars}">
                        <p:column headerText="Id">
                            <h:outputText value="#{car.id}" />
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="Year">
                            <h:outputText value="#{car.year}" />
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="Brand">
                            <h:outputText value="#{car.brand}" />
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="Color">
                            <h:outputText value="#{car.color}" />
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column style="width:32px">
                            <p:commandButton update=":carForm:display" oncomplete="PF('carDialog').show()" icon="ui-icon-search">
                                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{car}" target="#{dndCarsView.selectedCar}" />
                            </p:commandButton>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:dataTable>
                </p:outputPanel>
            </p:fieldset>

            <p:droppable for="selectedCars" tolerance="touch" activeStyleClass="ui-state-highlight" datasource="availableCars"
                         onDrop="handleDrop">
                <p:ajax listener="#{dndCarsView.onCarDrop}" update="dropArea availableCars" />
            </p:droppable>

            <p:dialog header="Car Detail" widgetVar="carDialog" resizable="false" draggable="false" showEffect="fade"
                      hideEffect="fade" modal="true">

                <p:outputPanel id="display">
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5" rendered="#{not empty dndCarsView.selectedCar}">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <p:graphicImage name="/demo/images/car/#{dndCarsView.selectedCar.brand}.gif" />
                        </f:facet>

                        <h:outputText value="Id" />
                        <h:outputText value="#{dndCarsView.selectedCar.id}" style="font-weight:bold" />

                        <h:outputText value="Year:" />
                        <h:outputText value="#{dndCarsView.selectedCar.year}" style="font-weight:bold" />

                        <h:outputText value="Brand" />
                        <h:outputText value="#{dndCarsView.selectedCar.brand}" style="font-weight:bold" />

                        <h:outputText value="Color:" />
                        <h:outputText value="#{dndCarsView.selectedCar.color}" style="font-weight:bold" />
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </p:outputPanel>
            </p:dialog>
        </h:form>

    </h:body>
</f:view>
```

My Bean:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import org.primefaces.event.DragDropEvent;

@ManagedBean(name = "dndCarsView")
@ViewScoped
public class DNDCarsView implements Serializable {

    private List<Car> cars;

    private List<Car> droppedCars;

    private Car selectedCar;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        cars = new ArrayList<Car>();
        cars.add(new Car(1, 2001, "toyota", "black"));
        cars.add(new Car(2, 2002, "honda", "yello"));
        cars.add(new Car(3, 2003, "ferrari", "white"));
        cars.add(new Car(4, 2004, "bmw", "green"));
        cars.add(new Car(5, 2005, "suzuki", "blue"));
        cars.add(new Car(6, 2006, "mazda", "brown"));
        cars.add(new Car(7, 2007, "audi", "halfwhie"));
        cars.add(new Car(8, 2008, "aqua", "neroon"));
        droppedCars = new ArrayList<Car>();
    }

    public void onCarDrop(DragDropEvent ddEvent) {
        Car car = ((Car) ddEvent.getData());

        droppedCars.add(car);
        cars.remove(car);
    }

    public List<Car> getCars() {
        return cars;
    }

    public List<Car> getDroppedCars() {
        return droppedCars;
    }

    public Car getSelectedCar() {
        return selectedCar;
    }

    public void setSelectedCar(Car selectedCar) {
        this.selectedCar = selectedCar;
    }

}
```

Comment: stiemannkj1 thanku for your reply.  stiemannkj1 simply if drop same portlet two time on same page issue will reproduced. first portlet drag and drop 
 working fine second portlet drag and drop will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running into [PrimeFaces Issue #3265: PrimeFaces Draggable/Droppable submits Ajax requests via the wrong form](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/3265). A simple workaround is to explicitly declare the form that you wish to use for Draggable/Droppable Ajax requests (using `h:form`'s `binding` and `p:ajax`'s `form` attributes):

```
<h:form id="carForm" binding="#{carForm}">
    <!-- Your code here.... -->
    <p:droppable for="selectedCars" tolerance="touch"
        activeStyleClass="ui-state-highlight" datasource="availableCars"
        onDrop="handleDrop">
        <p:ajax listener="#{dndCarsView.onCarDrop}"
            update="dropArea availableCars" form="#{carForm.clientId}" />
    </p:droppable>
</h:form>
```